# How many elements does the set $E$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime such that  $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Let $\mathbb{F}_p$  be the field  with   $p$ elements. Consider the subset  $E$ of  $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$  given by  $E =\{ (x,y)  \in \mathbb{F}_p\times \mathbb{F}_p : y^2 =x^3 +1 \}$, which  of the following are true?

1. $E$ has  at least two elements
2. $E$  has  at most  $2p$ elements
3. $E$ can have  $p^2$ elements
4. $E$  has  at least $2p$ elements

My attempt: I take $p= 5$ then $E =\{ (x,y)  \in \mathbb{F}_5 \times \mathbb{F}_5 : y^2 =x^3 +1 \}$
Here only two elements satisfy the set $E$, $(2,2)$ and $(2,3)$, $2^2=8+1 \pmod  5$ and $9=9 \pmod 5$

I think $E$   has  atleast  two elements

Comment: $(0,1)$... ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: okay @KReiser yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually: if $p\equiv 2\mod 3$, we can conclude that $x^3$ can range all remainders of $0,1,\dots,p-1$. because, if $0<x<y\le p-1$ $p|x^3-y^3\Rightarrow p|x^2+y^2+xy\Rightarrow p|(2x+y)^2+3y^2$ and therefore $-3$ is $p$'s quadratic residue, which contradict $p\equiv 2\mod 3$. Therefore for each $y$, there is exactly one $x$ such that $x^3\equiv y^2-1\mod p$. So we can know that $|E|=p$.

Comment: $p|x^2+y^2+xy\Rightarrow p|4(x^2+ y^2 + xy).$ Im not getting How do you  get $4?$

Comment: @user12392 If $p$ divides something, then $p$ divides four times something...